# self tooltip in listbox

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, listbox

I have a listox that bind to some `ObservableCollection<string>`, I want tooltip for each row to be the row content.

I have tried like:

```
<ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
             <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding MyList}"/>
          </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

In ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> _myList;
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyList
    {
        get { return _myList; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._myList)
                _myList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyList");
        }
    }
```

but it doesn't shows the tooltip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataContext of ListBoxItem is an element from MyList.

```
<ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
             <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding}"/>
          </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```